# Обновление страницы через заданный промежуток времени

Tags: c#

Как сделать обновление страницы, если ничего не меняется в течении 2 минут?

Comment: @giok404 Не забывайте принимать ответ (галочка), если он Вам помог.

Answer (score 2):

Создаешь System.Timers.Timer timer, задаешь интервал в две минуты и определяешь свое событие timer.Elapsed, в котором обновляешь страницу. По событию какого-нибудь изменения останавливаешь таймер(если он запущен), делаешь обновление и снова запускаешь таймер, и собственно если он отсчитал две минуты, то изменений не произошло...
Как-то так...

Comment: @AlexDenisov, а пример кода можно, как это выглядит?

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
```

где 10 - интервал обновления страницы в секундах.

Answer (score -1):

Ну, обычно запускают безусловный цикл и считаются секунды? В некоторых есть таймеры уже написанные, но, по сути, это всё тот же цикл только спрятанный в "коробку". Про С не знаю, так как не знаком...

Comment: >> Но, по сути, это всё тот же цикл только спрятанный в "коробку".  - откуда вы такое взяли? Так делали в очень старых программах когда не было многозадачности. Похоже что вы не только с С не знакомы, но и с таймерами как таковыми.

Comment: Да не знаком, пока что не приходилось использовать. Поясните если не затруднит.

Comment: Современные таймеры не реализуют через такой цикл. Почитайте первоисточники о том, как в ядрах операционных систем реализованы всякие таймеры и ожидающие операции с таймаутами. Один из вариантов реализации - это очередь ожидания, отсортированная в порядке близости срабатывания. Разумеется, вся эта дребедень уже реализована внутри ядра и нет нужды её реализоваывать самостоятельно. Все приличные рантаймы имеют API для таймеров и .NET не исключение (см. ответ 1101_debian)

Comment: хм ну ща почитаем... вот только ожидающая операция это вообще то по большому счёту тот же цикл который проверяется через определённый промежуток времени, или наступает из за определённого события. Ладно ща погуглю... А то что это уже реализовано в самом языке, я про это говорил.

Comment: Ну как я и думал... отличие API таймера от обыкновенно цикла в том, что API таймер считает стандартные секунды, а простой цикл пустой считает такты. Плюс API работает параллельно от кода... то есть выполняется основной код и таймер одновременно, цикл естественно тормозит всю программу. Но принцип один и тот же, цикл который проверяет каждый раз наступило ли время выполнить тело таймера.